# How do I pass photo(bitmaps) between two activities?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities my first class is: DfbActivity.java and my second class is: Tata.java

First class include two buttons(photo,add),an image view and an edit text when press photo button take a photo and show in imageview. Second class write a string on an image but I want to when I press add button in first class sends out the capture image and edit text's content to second class. I think use intent but I don't know how please help

Edit:

Thanks for answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8706912/1116478 they are work.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117818/how-to-send-a-bitmap-between-two-different-activity-classes-in-android

Comment: when I write in my first class Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtras("MYBITMAP",yourImage);
startActivity(intent);  is ok but when I write in my secınd class, Bitmap imageToDisplay = (Bitmap) this.getIntent().getExtras("MYBITMAP"); something is wrong :(

Comment: If the bitmap is large passing via intent can be really slow. You should consider saving the bitmap on the sd card and passing the link or something else like that.

Comment: eclipe give error it says: change the getIntent to getParent I'm new in android so don't know uses intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line doesn't seem to be correct:

```
Bitmap imageToDisplay = (Bitmap) this.getIntent().getExtras("MYBITMAP");
```

Try to use this instead:

```
Bitmap imageToDisplay = (Bitmap) this.getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("MYBITMAP");
```

Comment: @gulsen: What is the problem with this code? Which part doesn't work for you?
Here is the example of passing a bitmap with intent. This code works fine:
Activity1 (sending a bitmap):

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.sym_call_missed);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("b", bmp);
    startActivity(intent);

Activity #2 (receiver):

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) 
                   getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("b");
    }

Comment: thank you very much :) this code realy good problem is I didn't write public bitmap now it is work